# Plack::Builder - last line isn't using mount - error message

Tags: perl, plack

Having the next simple Plack app:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Plack::Builder;

my $app = sub { 
        return [ 200, [ 'Content-Type' => 'text/plain' ], [ 'Hello World' ] ]; 
};

builder {
    foreach my $act ( qw( /some/aa /another/bb  / ) ) {
        mount $act => $app;
    }
};
```

return's error:

```
WARNING: You used mount() in a builder block, but the last line (app) isn't using mount().
WARNING: This causes all mount() mappings to be ignored.
 at /private/tmp/test.psgi line 13.
Error while loading /private/tmp/test.psgi: to_app() is called without mount(). No application to build. at /private/tmp/test.psgi line 13.
```

but the next builder block is OK.

```
builder {
    foreach my $act ( qw( /some/aa /another/bb  / ) ) {
        mount $act => $app;
    }
    mount "/" => $app;
};
```

I understand than the [Plack::Builder manual](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Plack-1.0024/lib/Plack/Builder.pm) says

> NOTE: Once you use mount in your builder code, you have to use mount
>   for all the paths, including the root path (/).

But in the `for` loop i have the `/` mount as last one: `qw( /some/aa /another/bb  / )`, so something is here *behind the scene*.

Can anybody explain, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A look at the [source code](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MIYAGAWA/Plack-1.0024/lib/Plack/Builder.pm) help to understand what is going on:

```
sub builder(&) {
    my $block = shift;
    ...
    my $app = $block->();

    if ($mount_is_called) {
        if ($app ne $urlmap) {
            Carp::carp("WARNING: You used mount() in a builder block,
```

So, `builder` is just a subroutine and its argument is a code block. That code block is evaluated and the result ends up in `$app`. With your code, however, the result of the evaluation is the empty string which results from the terminating `foreach` loop:

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -e 'sub test{ for("a", "b"){ $_ } }; print Dumper(test())'
$VAR1 = '';
```

Since `mount foo => $bar` is "just" syntactic sugar that even gets hard to read in cases like yours, I suggest you move a tiny step towards the bare metal, skip the syntactic sugar and use  [Plack::App::URLMap](https://metacpan.org/module/Plack%3a%3aApp%3a%3aURLMap) directly:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Plack::App::URLMap;

my $app = sub { 
    return [ 200, [ 'Content-Type' => 'text/plain' ], [ 'Hello World' ] ]; 
};

my $map = Plack::App::URLMap->new;

foreach my $act ( qw( /some/aa /another/bb  / ) ) {
    $map->mount( $act => $app );
}

$map->to_app;
```